ESP32 BLE not turning off
I am working on a project that uses BLE. I am using the BLE library from arduino, and when I turn off the BLE by calling BLEDevice::deinit(true) the code gets stuck.
I made a deeper search and found that the code got stuck on one of the four functions inside the deinit function. The deinit function os composed of these four functions:
/* STATIC */ void BLEDevice::deinit(bool release_memory) {
if (!initialized) return;

esp_bluedroid_disable();
esp_bluedroid_deinit();
esp_bt_controller_disable();
esp_bt_controller_deinit();
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32
if (release_memory) {
    esp_bt_controller_mem_release(ESP_BT_MODE_BTDM);  // <-- require tests because we released classic BT memory and this can cause crash (most likely not, esp-idf takes care of it)
} else {
    initialized = false;   
} 
#endif

}
I found that the code stops on the function esp_bluedroid_disable();.
I don't have Wi-Fi on the project, so I would ask for help to understand what is going on here.

This seems to be a known issue, with an alternate repo that addresses it.

Sorry for my misunderstanding, but I cannot found that alternative repo...

I am using that library. Below I leave the first lines of my BLEDevice.cpp:
/*

BLE.cpp

Created on: Mar 16, 2017

 Author: kolban



*/
It is the same author.

As discussed in the comments, there was a problem on that BLE library of a memory leak.
The solution I found is to use another library. I used the Arduino BLE from Arduino: Arduino BLE
It also can be used on platformio projects:
Arduino BLE PlatformIO Registry
A useful tutorial can be found on this link:
Example
